# Generators of conformal transformations change of basis

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, commutator, lie-algebra

I recently started going through Introduction to Conformal Field Theory by Blumenhagen and Plauschinn ( [springer link](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9783642004490) ). On page 11, they glue together the generators of conformal transformations as follows:
$$J_{\mu,\nu} = L_{\mu \nu}\,\,\,,\,\,\,J_{-1, \mu} = \frac{1}{2}(P_{\mu} - K_{\mu})\,\,\,,\,\,\,J_{-1,0} = D\,\,\,,\,\,\,J_{0,\mu} = \frac{1}{2}(P_{\mu} + K_{\mu}).$$ 
In this chapter, the authors talk about conformal group in $d\geq3$. The sources of confusion are the following:

First kind is notational. It seems that here $\mu,\nu$ run from 1 to d-1. I was left with the impression that those were reserved by $\eta_{\mu\nu}=diag\{-1,...,1,...\}$ so I automatically assumed that they run from 0 to d-1. This seems to be in contradiction with the above definitions, since then $J_{\mu,\nu}$ would automatically include $J_{0,\nu}$ inside it, so the first and last equations would be equal and last would be redundant...
The other notational question is concerning $J_{\mu,\nu}$ itself - what does the comma between indices represent? Later on, the authors give the reason for combining the generators in such a way:

$$[J_{mn}, J_{rs}] = i(\eta_{ms}J_{nr} + \eta_{nr}J_{ms} - \eta_{mr}J_{ns} - \eta_{ns}J_{mr})$$, with $m,n = -1, 0, 1,...,(d-1)$. Here, the commas are not there anymore.

Second question is somehow connected to indices again - answers in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118890/commutation-relations-of-the-generators-of-the-conformal-group) say that this extra -1 index is not a spacetime dimension, but for the commutator above to work, we have added this component to $\eta$ which the authors use to represent the metric tensor. Maybe it would be clearer if we defined a new object, just like $J$, which would read $y_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}$, $y_{-1-1}=-1$, else $=0$ (I assume)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Greek indices $\mu,\nu,\ldots$ are the usual spacetime indices, so there are $d$ of them. In the conventions of your book, they run from $1,2,\ldots,d$. Likewise $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ is a $d \times d$ matrix. Depending on whether you're in the Euclidean or in Minkowski, $\eta_{\mu \nu} = \text{diag}(\pm 1,1,\ldots,1)$. This is all standard and has nothing to do with conformal field theory. The key point in CFT is that all the conformal generators form the Lie algebra of ${\frak so}(d+1,1)$ or ${\frak so}(d,2)$, again depending on the signature of spacetime. The authors organize all the generators in a $(d+2) \times (d+2)$ matrix of generators $J_{mn}$ with $m,n = -1,0,\ldots,d$. The comma in the indices means strictly nothing, except that it's "ugly" to write indices like $J_{-1\mu}$ or $J_{\nu 0}$ - this is a matter of aesthetics, not mathematics.

Your second question is not quite clear to me. Indeed instead of $\eta_{mn}$ you could write $X_{mn}$ or give the "metric" in $d+2$ dimensions another name - that's just a choice of conventions.

Finally there is a way to interpret the $-1$ and $0$ indices as spacetime indices. This involves the so-called *embedding formalism*. This is a trick to embed $\mathbb{R}^d$ or $\mathbb{R}^{1,d-1}$ in anti-de Sitter space of $d+2$ dimensions (but it's not directly related to AdS/CFT). In this higher-dimensional AdS space you identify real space (say $\mathbb{R}^d$) with the slice of points $X^A$ satisfying $X^A X_A = 0$ modulo the identification $X^A \sim \lambda X^A$. It can be shown that the spacetime symmetries of AdS then map 1-1 to conformal generators on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Likewise for $\mathbb{R}^{1,d-1}$. See for instance section 2.7 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04948.

Comment: I thought that common practice was greek letters to run from 0 to d-1 (usually 0 being reserved for time in Minkowski). In your notation, if greek letters run from 1 to d, you have -1 and 0 entries as well, then how, later on, do m and n run from -1 to (d-1)?

Comment: That's probably just a misprint in the book.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I took a look again at the other post I linked and the asker has the roman indices running up to d, not (d-1), so the greek indices run from 1 to d. However, in the next section, the authors say that the condition $\partial_\mu\epsilon_\nu + \partial_\nu\epsilon_\mu = 2/d (\partial_\dot{}\epsilon)\eta_{\mu\nu}$ in $d=2$ reads: $\partial_0\epsilon_0 = \partial_1\epsilon_1$, $\partial_0\epsilon_1 = -\partial_1\epsilon_0$. Here, they start from 0, not 1....

Comment: About my second question: as the accepted answer in the linked post says "Note that that −1 is not a spatial dimension with respect to spacetime but rather an additional dimension with respect to the group action". I guess I am having trouble imagining a line element $ds$ with such $\eta$.

Comment: Hi @VangelisVladimirov. You have to keep in mind that a book like this is written over a long period of time and in this case by two different authors. Unless they are extremely precise, there will be plenty of misprints and violations of conventions.

Indeed the fact that the $-1,0$ indices are non-physical (except when you use the embedding formalism) is non-intuitive. Ultimately the important thing is that there are symmetry generators that form an ${\frak so}(d,2)$ algebra. You can organize them however you want by performing a change of basis that affects $J_{mn}$ if you prefer.